# Adobe Acrobat form fields are all auto completing

Tags: forms, adobe, acrobat

In Acrobat preference I have auto complete turned off.
When I fill in one form field, all of the other form fields are filled in too with the same word?
So if I enter 'hello' into one field all the other form fields on the questionnaire get the value 'hello'.
I copied and pasted the form fields for each question to save time, surely that doesn't mean each form field in the questionnaire is just one form field, or does it? 
How can I separate each form field so it can hold its own answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question.

Fields with the same name will automatically get the same value, so each form field needs a different name.

If you create one form field, then right click on the form field in the menu on the right and choose 'place multiple fields', you can then input how many fields you want for the form along with other options. Acrobat then names each form field separately for you.